# Chain multiple calls with same arguments to return different results

Tags: unit-testing, dart, flutter, mockito

I'm in the process of writing a `Flutter` app with some extensive unit test coverage.
I'm using [Mockito](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mockito) to mock my classes.
Coming from a `Java` (`Android`) world where I can use `Mockito` to chain calls to return different values on subsequent calls.
I would expect this to work.

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

void main() {
  test("some string test", () {
    StringProvider strProvider = MockStringProvider();
    when(strProvider.randomStr()).thenReturn("hello");
    when(strProvider.randomStr()).thenReturn("world");

    expect(strProvider.randomStr(), "hello");
    expect(strProvider.randomStr(), "world");
  });
}

class StringProvider {
  String randomStr() => "real implementation";
}

class MockStringProvider extends Mock implements StringProvider {}
```

However it throws:

```
Expected: 'hello'
Actual:   'world'
  Which: is different.
```

The only working way I found that works is by keeping track myself.

```
void main() {
  test("some string test", () {
    StringProvider strProvider = MockStringProvider();

    var invocations = 0;
    when(strProvider.randomStr()).thenAnswer((_) {
      var a = '';
      if (invocations == 0) {
        a = 'hello';
      } else {
        a = 'world';
      }
      invocations++;
      return a;
    });

    expect(strProvider.randomStr(), "hello");
    expect(strProvider.randomStr(), "world");
  });
}
```

> 00:01 +1: All tests passed!

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a list and return the answers with `removeAt`:

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

void main() {
  test("some string test", () {
    StringProvider strProvider = MockStringProvider();
    var answers = ["hello", "world"];

    when(strProvider.randomStr()).thenAnswer((_) => answers.removeAt(0));

    expect(strProvider.randomStr(), "hello");
    expect(strProvider.randomStr(), "world");
  });
}

class StringProvider {
  String randomStr() => "real implementation";
}

class MockStringProvider extends Mock implements StringProvider {}
```

Comment: This seems like a reasonable alternative. Thanks

Comment: It seems that this is not working with Future return types, any alternatives?

Answer (score 8):

You're not forced to call `when` in the start of the test:

```
StringProvider strProvider = MockStringProvider();
when(strProvider.randomStr()).thenReturn("hello");
expect(strProvider.randomStr(), "hello");

when(strProvider.randomStr()).thenReturn("world");
expect(strProvider.randomStr(), "world");
```

Mockito is dart has a different behavior. Subsequent calls override the value.

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1 - With a Stub

I'm not sure about mockito, but you could do it using argument matchers, and creating a stub class that overrides that method instead of using a mock, like:

```dart
class StrProviderStub implements StrProvider {
    StrProviderStub(this.values);

    List<String> values;
    int _currentCall = 0;

    @override
    String randomStr() {
        final value = values[_currentCall];

        _currentCall++;

        return value;
    }
}
```

And then use that Stub instead of the mock on the test

## Option 2 - Use an Extension with a closure (Preferred)

```dart
extension MultipleExpectations<T> on PostExpectation<T> {
  void thenAnwserInOrder(List<T> bodies) {
    final safeBody = Queue.of(bodies);

    thenAnswer((realInvocation) => safeBody.removeFirst());
  }
}

# Then... use it like:
when(mock).thenAnwserInOrder(['First call', 'second call']);
```

I opened this issue to see if this could be added to the framework itself https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/issues/568