# Dart Mockito when first, second, ... n calls, return different value

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito

In Java Mockito, you can Mock a different returned value for each call like this:

```
when(myMock.doTheCall())
   .thenReturn("You failed")
   .thenReturn("Success");
```

Or like this:

```
when(myMock.doTheCall()).thenReturn("Success", "you failed");
```

Source: [Simulate first call fails, second call succeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785498/simulate-first-call-fails-second-call-succeeds)

I wonder how to achieve the same in Dart Mockito. I could not find a documentation for that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chain multiple calls with same arguments to return different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53896225/chain-multiple-calls-with-same-arguments-to-return-different-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this in 2020, three years later, it is  seems implemented

```
when(calculator.sum(any, any)).thenReturnInOrder([2, 4]);
```

https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/pull/597

Answer (score 7):

You can read the mockito documentation here:
https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/
The solution is using an ordered array of the responses you want. For your example:

```
final responses = ["You failed", "Success"];
when(myMock.doTheCall()).thenAnswer((_)=>responses.removeAt(0))
```

This also works with async responses (adding the async word to the method thenAnswer(...)).

Answer (score 3):

I've written a small extension based on the @Jhonatan's answer. It will return the list and stuck with the latest value for more calls.

```dart
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

extension When<T> on PostExpectation<T> {
  void thenReturnOneByOne(List<T> args) {
    assert(args.isNotEmpty, 'Argument list should not be empty!');
    thenAnswer((_) => 1 == args.length ? args[0] : args.removeAt(0));
  }
}
```

To use:

```dart
void main() {
   test('test', () {
      final clock = MockClock();
      when(clock.getMillis()).thenReturnOneByOne([5, 10, 30]);
      
      /// The values will be 5, 10, 30, 30, 30, 30...
   });
}
```