# Mock different answers and exceptions after several calls with Mocktail

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, mockito

I was using [mocktail](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail) for my unit testing and I could not find a way to **throw** an Exception on the **first call** but later, on the **second call**, **answer** with the right output.

I could find [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53897351/14559140) for two different answers but this was not enough for testing exceptions thrown. So I needed to come up with a modified solution.

This is what I wanted to achieve. By the way, I was testing a connection retry with http get.

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';

class MockClient extends Mock implements http.Client {}

final mockClient = MockClient();

//First time fails, second one retrieves a result. This doesn't work on Mocktail
when(() => mockClient.get(Uri.parse(url)))
  .thenThrow(SocketException()) // Call 1
  .thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(http.Response("page content", 200)) // Call 2
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After trying different ideas, a possible solution was to store each answer inside of a `List`

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';

class MockClient extends Mock implements http.Client {}

final mockClient = MockClient();

final List<Future<http.Response> Function(Invocation)> answers = [
 (_) => throw SocketException(),
 (_) => Future.value(http.Response("page content", 200)),
];


when(() => mockClient.get(Uri.parse(url)))
  .thenAnswer((invocation) => answers.removeAt(0)(invocation));
// Calling answers.removeAt(0) without the lambda method returns the same answer on all of them
```

In this example `Invocation` is not used and checks only 2 consecutive calls. But that behavior can be extended from what you can see here.

I haven't tried this with [Mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) but it should work in a similar way adapting the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @Cavitedev's answer, this is an extension that let's you mock multiple calls.

```dart
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';

extension WhenExtension<T> on When<T> {
  thenAnswerMany(List<Answer<T>> cbs) {
    return thenAnswer((invocation) {
      if (cbs.isEmpty) throw "No more answers available";
      return cbs.removeAt(0)(invocation);
    });
  }
}
```

to use

```dart
when(() => mock.call()).thenAnswerMany([
  (invocation) => result1,
  (invocation) => result2,
]);
```